# How to modify template type to be unsigned?

Tags: c++, templates, casting, type-conversion, unsigned-integer

```cpp
template<class T>
void foo(T s)
{
    unsigned T x = -1;
    //...
}

{
   int x = 129;
   foo(x);
}
```

How can I modify template type to be unsigned?
I know that this is bad practice due to the fact that not everything can be declared unsigned, but in special cases it makes sense.

I do not want to pass the modified type as a template argument. I want to modify the type in the function body itself.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. What do you want to change what to, based on what?

Comment: *This is bad practice due to the fact that not everything can be declared unsigned* -- If the compiler gives an error on instantiation, isn't that what you want?  That is to have the compiler check the type, and stop if an error is encountered?  I don't understand what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`std::make_unsigned`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/make_unsigned) to retrieve the unsigned type corresponding to an integral type.

```
#include <type_traits>

static_assert(
    std::is_same_v<
        unsigned int, 
        std::make_unsigned_t<int>
    >
);
```

Do note that your program will be ill-formed / exhibit undefined behavior if the template argument `T` isn't one of the enumerated valid types that `std::make_unsigned` accepts.